# web page template

Tags: templates, html

Is there any web page template and resources?

I am not good at image creating,page structure designing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean just for layout and styling?  A long time ago I used to use [TemplatesBox](http://www.templatesbox.com/), which worked pretty well for me at the time.  I would consider their free stuff to be a bit dated at this point, but it may do the job well enough for you.  A Google search for "free web site templates" will likely yield many more results.

With any templating system like that, I recommend not using it as copy-and-paste as they would expect.  Reference the free content, sure, but use it more as inspiration for your own code rather than just dropping it in place without fully understanding what it's doing.  Some templates can probably be streamlined more to be less image-heavy, some can have their style and markup more properly separated, etc.

Comment: In fact I prefer to the layout and color of the page rather than others.

Answer (score 1):

You might try the [YUI Grid Builder](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/builder/) from Yahoo, with more information available [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/).  There's also the [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/).